# Null pointer exception in CustomAdapter for custom list

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, custom-lists

I m creating an chat messenger. i m simply not getting any out put. Force stop accruing. Please help

Main code .java

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class Send extends Activity {

    static ListView msgList;
    Button send;
    EditText typeText;
    String Rid, name;
    static ArrayList<String> msg = new ArrayList<String>();
    static CustomAdapter adapter;
    Image image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
        Rid = settings.getString("regId", "");
        name = settings.getString("user_name", "");

        msgList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        typeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);
        String last_msg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("txt");

        msg.add("a");
        msg.add("b");
        msg.add("c");
        msg.add("d");
        msg.add("e");
        msg.add("f");
        msg.add("g");
        msg.add("h");
        msg.add("i");

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(Send.this, msg);
        msgList.setAdapter(adapter);


        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.send))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        ArrayList<String> regIds = new ArrayList<String>();
                        regIds.add(Rid);

                        // if you want more devices to receive this message just
                        // add their regID
                        // in this arrayList
                        GCMMessageSender sender = new GCMMessageSender();
                        sender.send(sender.createContent(name, typeText
                                .getText().toString(), regIds, Rid, image));
                    }
                });

    }

    public static class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Explicitly specify that GcmMessageHandler will handle the intent.
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    GcmMessageHandler.class.getName());

            // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is
            // launching.
            startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    };

    public static class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService {

        String mes, text, RId, type, reg, group_name;
        ArrayList<String> reg_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String active;
        private Handler handler;

        public GcmMessageHandler() {
            super("GcmMessageHandler");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate();
            handler = new Handler();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you
            // received
            // in your BroadcastReceiver.
            String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

            type = extras.getString("type");
            mes = extras.getString("title");
            text = extras.getString("message");
            RId = extras.getString("Rid");

            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this
                    .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            // get the info from the currently running task
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am
                    .getRunningTasks(1);

            Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"
                    + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            active = componentInfo.getClassName();

            if (type.equals("message"))
                notifyMessage();

            Log.i("GCM",
                    "Received : (" + messageType + ")  "
                            + extras.getString("title"));

            GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

        }

        public void insertToList(String text) {
            msg.add(text);
//          adapter.updateReceiptsList(msg);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //msgList.setSelection(msg.size());
        }


        public void notifyMessage() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), active,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if (active.equals("com.example.notification.Send")) {
                        insertToList(text);
                    }else{
                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                            GcmMessageHandler.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle(mes)
                            .setContentText(text)
                            .setSound(
                                    RingtoneManager
                                            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                            .setAutoCancel(true);

                    // // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(GcmMessageHandler.this,
                            Send.class);
                    resultIntent.putExtra("txt", text);
                    resultIntent.putExtra("regId", RId);
                    resultIntent
                            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
                                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder
                            .create(GcmMessageHandler.this);

                    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Send.class);

                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

                    PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            GcmMessageHandler.this, 0, resultIntent, 0);

                    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder
                            .getPendingIntent(0,
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    // // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
                    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
                }
                }
            });

        }

    }

}
```

Trying to display a list of string using a Custom Array Adapter. However every time I run my application I get error

This is my Custom List Adapter class:

CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.example.notification;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList <String> msg;
    ArrayList <String> date;
    ArrayList<Image> image;
    Activity context;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> msg) {

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        //super(context, msg);
        this.context=context;
        this.msg=msg;

    }

    public void updateReceiptsList(ArrayList<String> newlist) {
        this.msg.clear();
        this.msg = newlist;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return msg.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
View view=convertView;
UserHolder holder = null;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new UserHolder();
            String name = msg.get(position);
            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (context).getLayoutInflater();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msg_list_row, parent, false);

                holder.eventName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.msgTextView);
            } else {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (context).getLayoutInflater();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

                holder.eventName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event);

            }
            eventName.setText(name);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }else  {
            holder = (UserHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
    static class UserHolder {
        TextView eventName;
        }
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat of the error please

Comment: What error/exception message are you getting? Please post here.

Comment: Thanks for the afford. I already solved my problem. I started the cde from beginning.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to change your `view` instead of your `convertview` then you must return it:

`View view=convertView;` then return `view` instead: `return view;`

Also your textview content assignment should stay outside the outer if and not like you're doing it (`eventName.setText(name);`)

It should look like

```
 holder.eventName.setText(name);
```

and should stay just before the return method.